# Enterprise Architect: create a return message in sequence diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I have the following sequence diagram:

[image]

How do I change the message which comes from Object2 to Object1 to contain a return result message and not a method call.

Comment: Use the `Is Return` checkbox - https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/sequencemessage.html

Answer (score 1):

As xmojmr said:

[image]
in the context menu / Properties of the message.